# How can I calculate the factorial of a double in c++

Tags: c++, math

I am hoping there is a library function somewhere that can do this.
And yes it is very important that it be the factorial of a double value (that is it needs to work with non-integer values).

Comment: Are you thinking of the gamma function, or something else? "factorial" is normally only defined for integers.

Comment: The gamma function will allow me to do what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C99 standard library contains the gamma function, `double tgamma(double)`. This is closely related to the factorial, so you can define:

```
#include <cmath>

double factorial(double x) {return std::tgamma(x+1);}
```

This should be available in any C++11 implementation, but is not guaranteed to be in a C++03 implementation, which might only include the C90 library. If your implementation doesn't have it, then the Boost.Math library does.

Comment: OP should keep in mind, though, that this is only a numerical **approximation** to the gamma-function, subject to both rounding and approximation errors.  Don't expect, for instance, that `factorial(5.0) == 120.0`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Indeed, any use of floating-point arithmetic is only an approximation to real arithmetic.

Comment: I think @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft is trying to say that the result of the function need not be one of the two doubles that are closest to the real result.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: According to the Linux manpage, "This  function  had  to be called "true gamma function" since there is already a function gamma(3) that returns something else". It seems that on some ancient versions of Unix, `gamma()` returned the logarithm of the gamma function (now standardised to `lgamma()`).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a factorial cannot be defined for non-integers, but a common generalization is the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html), defined for all positive reals and all negative non-integers.

The [Boost::Math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/html/index.html) library contains a [tgamma()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/tgamma.html) function to calculate this with a real input and real output.

Answer (score 2):

Factorial is for integers. What you're probably looking for is the gamma function. On integer values Gamma(x) == Factorial(x-1), and gamma is defined for all numbers.  There's a library function for it: tgamma defined in header math.h